# Maps - keep getting hashcodes instead of accessing values

Tags: java

I have created a Map as follows:

```
private Map<String, List<Client>> clientCatalogue;
this.clientCatalogue = new TreeMap<String, List<Client>>();
```

The keys are client names, and the values are a list of client details.

I am iterating over it using keySet().  I want to access each list of values associated with the keys one at a time, and then do further processing on each before moving on to the next list of values. I have copied the values into a List type variable (clientDetails) and thought I'd print them out to check them.  But I keep getting hashcodes back.  Why is this, and what can I do to unpack these hashcodes and access the values I want?  Any suggestions appreciated.

```
List<Client> clientDetails;
clientDetails = new ArrayList<Client>();
for (String eachClient : this.clientCatalogue.keySet())
{
  clientDetails = clientCatalogue.get(eachClient);
  System.out.println("Details of client are: " + clientDetails);
}
```

Comment: You know you don't need to declare and initialize variables on separate lines, right?

Comment: If you are just going to use the key to look up the value, you can iterate over `values()`. If you need both, iterate over `entrySet()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (String eachClient : this.clientCatalogue.keySet())
{
    List<Client> clientDetails; = clientCatalogue.get(eachClient);

    for(Client cl : clientDetails)
    {

         System.out.println("Details of client are: " + cl.toString());
    }
}
```

The problem was that you were printing the list as a whole instead of the individual clients in the list.

BTW, you need a proper implementation for the `toString()` method in your `Client` class.

Also you do not need to create a new instance for `List<Clients> clientDetails`.

Also, if you do not want to iterate on the keys but on the values directly do this:

```
for (List<Client> clientDetails : this.clientCatalogue.values())
{
    for(Client cl : clientDetails)
    {    
         System.out.println("Details of client are: " + cl.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override **toString()** method in **Client** class. When you try to print any object through sysout then its toString method will be called, In your case its called of the Object's class. So override it as how you want sysout print it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `toString()` in your `Client` class to return the details you want to see printed.

Answer (score 0):

TreeMap inherits it's toString method from AbstractMap which it looks like will attempt to output a pretty representation of the map, but if you haven't given a toString implementation of clientDetails you aren't going to get anything pretty.  A  sample of your string output would help to know for sure though.